# How to obtain statistics from an intersection?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, intersection

I am new to the earth engine. My question is on how to obtain statistics from the overlapping region of two areas.

I have uploaded a table that contains the locations of river basins (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/basins/AqueductBasins). These commonly lie in several countries. I want to obtain the information on the mean population density for these basin areas in a specific country (so: mean for Basin1 in CountryA, mean for Basin1 in CountryB, mean in Basin2 in CountryA and so on).

I have taken this feature collection on the country borders:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw');
```

This image contains information on the people per cell:

```
var Pop2015 = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/2015');
```

I want to print a table with the average people per cell in the basin area in the different riparian states.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible as follows, where 'table' is the feature collection of river basins:

```
// First, we need to het the geometry of the intersection between every country and basin
// We will save every intersection to a new feature with a property named 'Country' and 'OBJECTID'
// we will add a property 'area' to filter intersection without area and 
// 'avgPeople' as the mean of the pop2015 image in the area of intersection
var mapping = countries.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var Country = feat.get('Country');
  var mapping2 = table.map(function(feat2){
    feat2 = ee.Feature(feat2);
    var OBJECTID = feat2.get('OBJECTID');
    var intersection = feat.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry());
    var avgPeople = Pop2015.reduceRegion({
      reducer: 'mean',
      geometry: intersection, 
      scale: 250,
      maxPixels: 10e9
    }).values().get(0);
    return ee.Feature(intersection, {OBJECTID: OBJECTID, Country: Country, 
                                      area: intersection.area(), avgPeople: avgPeople});
  });  
  return mapping2;
})
  // filter on intersections which did not return any overlapping area
  .flatten().filter(ee.Filter.gt('area', 0));
```

You will have to export the resulting feature collection to your assets/drive, as it will run out of memory for a worldwide calculation. In the example I show you in the link I filtered both feature collection (basins, countries) on a area of interest, so the result can be printed in the console: [link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd25f867db6788cd48a0527b1b7fef72)